# Don't understand how to connect device to Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools

This is what I found in developer android to connect device:

```
You can now connect your device with USB. You can verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices from the android_sdk/platform-tools/ directory.
```

Here's the android_sdk/platform-tools/ directly and I don't see any adb devices.

[image]

What is an add device command and where do I find this from the android_sdk/platform-tools/ directory?

Comment: Make sure your device is in Developer's Mode.

Comment: I have the USB debugging on and Developer Options ON in my device.

Answer (score 2):

`adb devices` is a command, not any tool or directory. Go to `android_sdk/platform-tools/` directory from terminal and run `adb devices` command.

Comment: How do I go to this directly from terminal? What terminal? You mean terminal from my application folder in my Mac?

Comment: Do you know location of your `android_sdk/platform-tools/` on your Mac?

Comment: Only what you see above in screenshot, Android SDK Platform-Tools. Do I have to update it and it'll show me the terminal?

Comment: Above screenshot is from your Android Studio. Right? From Android Studio, copy `Android SDK Location`, in my case it is `/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk`. Now open terminal. Next, type `cd /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk` and you will be in platform-tools. Next, type `adb devices` command to see if your device is connected

Comment: You mean the View -> Tool Windows ->Terminal? I copied and pasted /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk (with my name) and it says "bash: cd/: No such file or directory"

Comment: `/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk` this is my path. For your case please check in Android Studio (same window from where you took above screenshot)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158459/discussion-between-vicjordan-and-ibek).